# Execute script but don't touch workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, workspace

Can I execute script, but make it doesn't touch any current workspace variables? I.e. turn script into function?

Also it would be good to have access this script's variables after run.

I tried

```
evalin('myworkspace', 'myscript')
```

but it failed.

I tried

```
evalin('caller', 'myscript')
```

but it changed variables.

Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: Why can't you turn the script into a function? you just need to add 1 line.

Comment: You could run it as a function so as to isolate the base workspace, and output all the variables you want to reference afterwards in a struct. There is at least one [File Exchange submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36257-save-workspace-to-struct) which saves your entire workspace to a struct which you could run at the end of your function.

Comment: @AnderBiguri of course I know how to workaround; but I am checking if pre-made approach exists

Comment: @Dims I believe the "proper way" is making it a function. Whatever alternative would be hacky.

Comment: @AnderBiguri if there were named workspaes in Matlab, this also would be good to know

Comment: If either of the questions helped you, please consider upvoting them and accepting either of them. If not, please elaborate on which part of your question, that has not been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parallel computing toolbox, you can do it by submitting the script to your local cluster. (Just to emphasise, your local cluster is your own pc.)

E.g. if you have a script `SO.m` with the line

```
a = randn;
```

then you can submit and wait using

```
job = batch('SO', 'Profile', 'local');
wait(job);
```

Once it have finished running, you can load the variables using

```
M = load(job);
```

then all the variables are fields of `M`.

```
>> M.a

ans =

    0.4010
```

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way to accomplish this without changing the script itself would be to:

```
save
myscript
% ... examine variables
clear
load
```

[`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) saves the current workspace to a MAT-file called "matlab.mat". You can give it a different name if you prefer. `load` loads it in again. If you specified a different name for `save`, give the same name to `load`.